# r OpenStreetMap installation Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: r

I updated to R 3.4.0 on my Ubuntu 16.04 32 bit and now I cannot install `OpenStreetMap` anymore.
All other packages work fine. I have tried removing R and reinstalling it, but the problem persists.
Any hints on what to do?

```
R CMD INSTALL OpenStreetMap_0.3.3.tar.gz 
* installing to library ‘/home/berry/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
* installing *source* package ‘OpenStreetMap’ ...
** package ‘OpenStreetMap’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** data
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
in method for ‘raster’ with signature ‘"osmtile"’: no definition for class “osmtile”
in method for ‘raster’ with signature ‘"OpenStreetMap"’: no definition for class “OpenStreetMap”
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/home/berry/R/i686-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/OpenStreetMap’
```

The same error happens when using `install.packages("OpenStreetMap")` directly in R.

Comment: It's very strange to have a segmentation fault for a package which doesn't need compilation. I'd check the dependencies, and in particular `rJava`. Try to reinstall `rJava` before reinstalling `OpenStreetMap`. Also `rgdal` might need a reinstall (although I'd bet on `rJava` being the culprit).

Comment: If you just need OSM data in R, you can try this new package https://github.com/osmdatar/osmdata it relies on overpass API (no Java)

Comment: I tried reinstalling both. I completely removed and reinstalled R (including removing all library folders). I still get the same error. library(rJava) and library(rgdal) both work fine.  gdalinfo --version gives me GDAL 2.1.0, released 2016/04/25, so that seems fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it might be a bug, as some others have suggested: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45163268/3224432

A reported workaround is setting a flag for Java. This can be done in the R session via:

```
options(java.parameters = "-Xss2560k") # or different parameters
```