# RMongo installation fails with Segmentation Fault in Ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu, linux-kernel, segmentation-fault, rjava

I've been for last couple of hours trying to install the **RMongo** package with the following output:

```
> install.packages("RMongo")
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
trying URL 'https://repo.bppt.go.id/cran/src/contrib/RMongo_0.0.25.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 4169519 bytes (4.0 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 4.0 MB

* installing *source* package ‘RMongo’ ...
** package ‘RMongo’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/RMongo’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpHZoomn/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("RMongo") :
  installation of package ‘RMongo’ had non-zero exit status
```

I've also identified the same error trying to install **xlsx**.

I don't know what has changed in the past distros, since I've tried this with Ubuntu 16.04.2 and Ubuntu 17.04, with the same result.

This is a description of the R environment in the Ubuntu 16.04.2 distro:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3.6.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3.6.0
locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=es_ES.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=es_ES.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=es_ES.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=es_ES.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       
attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_3.4.0 tools_3.4.0    tcltk_3.4.0
```

Any idea about what can be happening?

Answer (score 3):

linux-image-3.13.0-121-generic and linux-image-4.4.0-81-generic contain a fix for the [Stack Clash vulnerability](https://askubuntu.com/a/927190/66509).

Be careful with kernel updates, which fix this vulnerability. Current patch breaks many java (sun/oracle and openjdk) applications. See [Bug #1699772: linux-image-4.4.0-81-generic, linux-image-3.13.0-121-generic Regression: many user-space apps crashing](https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1699772). The solution is to temporary reboot system with old kernel (linux-image-3.13.0-119-generic in Trusty).

Ubuntu kernel developers [will prepare new patch in a few days](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel-discuss/2017-June/017507.html).

**UPDATE:** Latest updates (at least image-4.4.0-83-generic, linux-image-4.8.0-58-generic, linux-image-4.10.0-26-generic) fix this vulnerability and problems with user-space programs.

Comment: After the last kernel update, from 4.4.0-81 to 4.4.0-83, the problem has been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer to the problems that I'm experiencing with RMongo, but solves the problem for me, so I hope it can be useful.

I've continued making some tests. Since this problem started when RMongo suddenly stopped from working, and taking into account that I had a similar installation that was working properly, I started to compare both environments.

I've checked that, in the system that is failing, some software updates were performed (you can check them below):

```
The following NEW packages will be installed
  libmircommon7 libmircore1 linux-headers-4.4.0-81 linux-headers-4.4.0-81-generic linux-image-4.4.0-81-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-81-generic
The following packages will be upgraded:
  click firefox firefox-locale-en flashplugin-installer gir1.2-click-0.4 google-chrome-stable grub-common grub-pc
  grub-pc-bin grub2-common libc-bin libc-dev-bin libc6 libc6:i386 libc6-dbg libc6-dev libclick-0.4-0 libepoxy0
  libgnutls-openssl27 libgnutls30 libmirclient9 libmircookie2 libmirprotobuf3 libmwaw-0.3-3 libnss3 libnss3-nssdb
  libqt5concurrent5 libqt5core5a libqt5dbus5 libqt5gui5 libqt5network5 libqt5opengl5 libqt5printsupport5 libqt5sql5
  libqt5sql5-sqlite libqt5test5 libqt5widgets5 libqt5xml5 libssl-dev libssl-doc libssl1.0.0 libvlc5 libvlccore8
  libzzip-0-13 linux-firmware linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic linux-libc-dev locales multiarch-support
  openssl python3-click-package vlc vlc-data vlc-nox vlc-plugin-notify vlc-plugin-samba
```

So, I've checked one by one this packages, and it turns out that the root of the problem is the new kernel **4.4.0-81**.

In order to be sure that this is the root of the problem, I've launched by Ubuntu distro with the previous version of the kernel that I had in my laptop: **4.4.0-79**

And this is the result of the installation:

```
> install.packages("RMongo")
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
--- Please select a CRAN mirror for use in this session ---
trying URL 'https://pbil.univ-lyon1.fr/CRAN/src/contrib/RMongo_0.0.25.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 4169519 bytes (4.0 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 4.0 MB

* installing *source* package ‘RMongo’ ...
** package ‘RMongo’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (RMongo)

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpJScKfz/downloaded_packages’
> install.packages("xlsx")
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://pbil.univ-lyon1.fr/CRAN/src/contrib/xlsx_0.5.7.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 312839 bytes (305 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 305 KB

* installing *source* package ‘xlsx’ ...
** package ‘xlsx’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (xlsx)

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpJScKfz/downloaded_packages’
```

Both packages, **xlsx** and **RMongo**, are now successfully installed and working.

I've also checked the relationship between **xlsx** and **RMongo**, and I'm afraid that problem underneath is **rJava** (common dependency). As a matter of fact, in order to be sure about this, I've made tests with other packages rJava-dependant (**RWeka**) and I had the same problem, solved after changing the kernel version.

**== UPDATE ==**

After the last kernel update, from 4.4.0-81 to 4.4.0-83, the problem has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem (at least for package "xlsx") occurs in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with kernel 3.13.0-121-generic. When booting with the previous kernel (3.13.0-119-generic) installation works and library loads.

UPDATE: problem appears to be solved in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS by new kernel 3.13.0-123-generic

Comment: The same happens here with Debian and kernel 4.9.0-3-amd64.