# openNLPdata Segmentation fault (core dumped) with R

Tags: r, rstudio, opennlp

I need install openNLPdata, but when I use

```
install.packages("openNLPdata", dependencies = TRUE)
```

Give this error

```
install.packages("openNLPdata", dependencies = TRUE)
Installing package into ‘/home/guihathy/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
tentando a URL 'https://ftp.igh.cnrs.fr/pub/CRAN/src/contrib    /openNLPdata_1.5.3-2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 7318681 bytes (7.0 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 7.0 MB

* installing *source* package ‘openNLPdata’ ...
** package ‘openNLPdata’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
No man pages found in package  ‘openNLPdata’ 
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/home/guihathy/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/openNLPdata’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpKmuUTw/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("openNLPdata", dependencies = TRUE) :
  installation of package ‘openNLPdata’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: OBS: I use Ubuntu 16.4

Comment: Seems like an issue related to kernel. Read
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44699417/3592342