# RMarkdown Shiny crashes when rendering ggplot plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, r-markdown, opennlp

I am trying to create an interactive markdown file using shiny and I am facing issues with using ggplot with libraries that use rJava. Using rJava does not seem to cause a problem.

I had to use openNLP for some text mining operations I wanted to do and it caused the document to crash when I was rendering a `ggplot` plot using `renderPlot` (completely unrelated to using openNLP) exactly the **2nd time**.

I later noticed that this happens when I just import any library that uses `rJava`.

Some libraries I tried and got the same reaction: *openNLP, RWeka, wordnet, Rdrools*

I have added a sample gist below for others to try.

[gist for the sample Rmd](https://gist.github.com/ashraaghav/1d02dd8d1d519f3703d97bf7de57192c)

I couldn't figure out why this is happening. Any tips to overcome this would be appreciated.

```
R version:         3.4.0
Shiny version:     1.0.5
rmarkdown version: 1.5
pandoc version:    1.19.2.1
```

**Edit**: This seems to be a problem only on versions 3.4.0 or higher.

Comment: I think the problem lays in your `uiOutput("ggOut")`. I think it is NOT possible to have multiple outputs passed to a single `uiOutput`...

Comment: No. It happens even when I just have a `plotOutput` instead of a UI output and try to render the plot. Also, the same `uiOutput` works when I dont import the above mentioned libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this was an issue that has been faced before too, I am posting the solution so that it helps someone.

Adding an additional java parameter helped solve the problem.

```
options(java.parameters = "-Xss2560k")
```

Relevant SO question: [rjava dependent package installation Segmentation fault (core dumped)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44682540/rjava-dependent-package-installation-segmentation-fault-core-dumped)